# Properly extracting archives with Mac metadata

Tags: linux, macos, zip

Someone has sent me a zip file containing some fonts. I extracted it using `unzip` under Linux, and there are empty files in the top level of the archive, and some files similarly named but beginning with `._` in a `__MACOSX` subdirectory.

I understand that the `__MACOSX` contents should be metadata, and normally I'd delete it. In this case, however, all of the data seems to be in there!

Is there a tool that I can use to reassemble the original data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The file must be flattened on a OS X machine first.

Comment: [related topic](http://superuser.com/questions/54737/converting-fonts-from-os-x-to-linux-centos).

Comment: [Also related](http://superuser.com/q/198569/35484) and applicable to non-font archives.

Comment: ever consider the possibility that it can work, because i have it working now. In terminal I use unzip command and files inflate but then i get an error at the end, that error is the problem with the metadata but i still have all my files and no harm done. So you can use command line and ignore error.