# Create .zip's on OS X without the "extra" MacOS files (like .DS_Store, MACOSX folder, etc)

Tags: macos, zip, finder, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compressing folders on a mac, without the .DS_Store](https://superuser.com/questions/198569/compressing-folders-on-a-mac-without-the-ds-store)

OS X includes undesired, "extra" files when creating .zip's of folders that look poor in Windows & Linux.  How to rectify?

This [Create Zip Files Without Any Mac-Specific “Extras” Inside](http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/general-software/create-zip-files-without-any-mac-specific-extras-inside/) references ZipCleaner, which appears to be no longer downloadable given MobileMe is shut down (as of 2012-07-02).

Would prefer some solution that doesn't require me to a "fix" a .zip file that's created, but rather just create the .zip correctly the first time, executable from both Finder and Terminal.app cmdline.  Anything exist?  (Will take as a replacement/workaround to post-creation "fix" the .zip if no proper-.zip-creation method exists.)

Answer (score 1):

Info-ZIP does not yet support compressing the resource fork, which makes it suitable for this. When it does, its `-df` option will tell it to only compress the data fork.

Comment: Is this the Info-ZIP you speak of?  http://www.info-zip.org/

Comment: Yes, but you probably already have it. Try `man zip`.